# ES6; Nested Promise.all (Maybe?)

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

The post title may not be entirely accurate as I'm not even sure if my approach to this is the best way. I'll let the community decide.

Working with Javascript(ES6), in a React app.
Example Data (Original):

```
dataArray = 
[
{"uid": 3, "region": "bru", "hostname": "bru-002.domain.com", "status": "active"}, 
{"uid": 1, "region": "bru", "hostname": "bru-001.domain.com", "status": "disabled"},
{"uid": 4, "region": "apc", "hostname": "apc-001.domain.com", "status": "active"}
];
```

- The object key names with-in each array are static. We can assume if there is an object, it will contain the key name 'hostname', etc.
- Live data will have hundreds of entries for each region and dozens of other object fields (keys). Not really relevant for the code, just FYI.

The end goal is to perform a HTTP request for each host and collect the results from the request. That functionality is already written and in use.
The brain-breaker I've run into is a CR to separate these calls into 'blocks by region'. In other words, **perform all calls for first region and when that is done, THEN initiate calls for next region**, etc. The final results of all calls will go into a setState().

The existing code uses Promise instead of async/await. Most of the time I use await, but in some cases I do like the clear code readability that a Promise in conjuction with a .then provides.

This is a snippet of current in-use code. It's in an useEffect block.:

```
...
Promise.all(
  dataArray.map(function(host) {
    if (host['status'] !== 'disabled') {
     // pinger() is a function that makes the calls.
     // Assume it returns what we want.
      return pinger(host.hostname); 
    }
    return ''; // Default return to satisfy map function
  }))
  .then(result => {
    setPingedData(result); // Using a React set State
  }
);
...
```

The above code works, but en masse. To separate it out, I started by creating a new object that ends up looking like this:

```
sortedByRegionObj = 
{ "bru": [{"uid": 3, "hostname": "bru-002.domain.com", "status": "active"}, 
          {"uid": 1, "hostname": "bru-001.domain.com", "status": "disabled"}],
  "apc": [{"uid": 4, "hostname": "apc-001.domain.com", "status": "active"}]
};
```

- The top level object key names represent 'region groups'.
- The region names will be dynamic. We can only assume if there is a region, the value of that region will be an array of 1 or more objects.
- The arrays represent how we want to group the HTTP calls. The array would be one group of Promises.

And the idea was to walk through the object using something like:

```
for (const regionArray of Object.values(sortedByRegionObj)) {
 Promise.all(
          regionArray.map(function(host) {
...
```

(The above code is not valid- just depicting the general idea)

and create Promise arrays and then use Promise.all... but then I got lost. The part that stumped me was having a dynamic number of objects when trying to create an array for Promise.all...
I can't wrap my head around how to do this.

Thoughts?

Comment: So have you got a function to create the separated-by-region-name object by taking in the "en masse" array of objects?

Comment: "*The part that stumped me was having a dynamic number of objects when trying to create an array for `Promise.all`*" - but you already did that just fine? Your working code handles a `dataArray` with a dynamic number of objects, and so does the new code with the `regionArray`.

Comment: To "*perform all calls for first region and when that is done, THEN initiate calls for next region*", use an `await` in a loop. Doing that with promises is possible but much uglier.

Comment: I'd use Array.filter instead of map, you might get some undefined elements in your mapped array.

Comment: `The above code is not valid- just depicting the general idea` -- I think you're wrong in this. The code you wrote is the answer to your question except you've forgotten to await the `Promise.all` -- `for (.....) { let regionData = await Promise.all(....`. You've basically answered your own question in the qustion itself without realising it. You're stumped because you forgot the await

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this:

```js
const dataArray = [
  { uid: 3, region: "bru", hostname: "bru-003.domain.com", status: "active" },
  { uid: 3, region: "bru", hostname: "bru-002.domain.com", status: "active" },
  { uid: 1, region: "bru", hostname: "bru-001.domain.com", status: "disabled" },
  { uid: 4, region: "apc", hostname: "apc-001.domain.com", status: "active" },
];

const pingHosts = async (data) => {
  const regions = new Set(data.map((d) => d.region));
  const results = {};
  for (const region of regions) {
    results[region] = await Promise.all(
      data
        .filter((d) => d.status !== "disabled" && d.region === region)
        .map((host) => pinger(host.hostname)),
    );
  }
  return results;
};

// simulate network request
const pinger = (hostname) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`pinger: ${hostname}`);
    resolve(`pinger: ${hostname}`);
  }, 500);
})

console.log('results: ', await pingHosts(dataArray));
```

demo: https://livecodes.io/?x=id/mndyfu329vr&console=open